# Random Autofill in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I am having a strange problem with Azure DevOps. I realize this isn't exactly a coding question, but I have been unable to find anyone with a similar problem on any other forums. I am using Azure DevOps to manage user stories and tasks for a team of developers. The issue I have is when typing in the body of any task, bug, or user story whatever I am typing will autofill to a (seemingly) random word and the cursor will jump back to the beginning of the field. Latest example, I attempted to type "Waiting on new documents from client" as a comment in a task, and halfway through typing the word "Waiting" it auto-corrected it to the word "Hone" and the cursor moved back to the beginning of the field.

I've checked keyboard settings, but nothing seemed out of the ordinary. I've also made sure that all drivers are up to date. Has anyone experienced something similar with Azure DevOps (or any other programs for that matter)? The machine is a Microsoft Surface Book 2 running Windows 10 Enterprise Edition.

I'm at a loss for what to do to fix the issue. For now, I have been typing all descriptions/comments in an empty Word doc and copy/pasting to the board item in Azure DevOps but that is quickly becoming cumbersome.

Comment: Sounds like a browser issue to me.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try that first. Switched to Chrome and so far it seems to be working...

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a browser issue. I don't know why I didn't try this first but I switched to Chrome and it seems to be working fine. For whatever reason the issue only occurs sporadically on Edge. Thank you Daniel for the suggestion.